# Is it possible to have access to neo4j configurations in a user defined procedure?

Tags: neo4j, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a user defined procedure in neo4j which requires having access to neo4j configurations. I can see in the [documentations](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/procedure/Procedure.html) that `@Context` is used to inject `GraphDatabaseService` and `Log` objects but I don't see anything for config object.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need   org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config package.

Good example in APOC:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.2/src/main/java/apoc/ApocConfiguration.java